# Making sure each method ends with a specific statement

Tags: python

Suppose you want to write a class in which each method should end with a specific statement `print "hello world"` (just an example).  The simplest approach would be to simply write this statement at the end of each method you are writing.

```
class Example(object):
  def method1(self):
    ...
    print "hello world"
  def method2(self):
    ...
    print "hello world"
  ...
```

But what happens when a colleague will extend the class 5 years later and never heard about that each method should end with that statement? Then it simply wasn't enough to write the statement at the end of each method manually. But how could you achieve this anyway, even for extended classes and methods that are added later on? Maybe with decorators?

Comment: *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?* Who remembers to apply the decorators, or or or... Why not just document it, or make sure testing  checks these things... but then, someone could forget to update the test... - is there an *actual problem* you're trying to solve here - if so, what is it?

Comment: It would help if you could explain more what kind of thing should be done at the end of each method; also if those methods are called manually or through some internal mechanism (in which case you can—and should—move that code there).

Comment: Well there is a way to apply something to "all methods" as in "interpreter, please find yourself every method and apply it" or there isn't. If you don't know such a way than a more concrete example wouldn't really help you, right?

Comment: If you're looking to the language to enforce today's design decision, you'll be disappointed and the future will just discard your code. This is why we don't like abstract questions 'round here.

Comment: @erikb85 I do know multiple ways how this could be done; knowing exactly what you are trying to do would help to tell you what would be an good solution, or to make you change your application design so you wouldn’t need this in the first place.

Comment: Because there is a lot of closing/reopening discussion going on: Please read the question again. I am not asking to solve a specific problem at hand, true. But the question is actually quite specific. It asks for a language feature, which might exist or not. The only existing answer right now is showing that such a feature can be implemented, although it's probably not the Pythonic way to solve any problem. I ask all *close* voters to reconsider the difference between an unspecific question and a problem which currently might not have a practical solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you really want to, you could use something like this, although I think it's somewhat hackish:

```
class Example(object):
  def method1(self):
    print 1
  def method2(self):
    print 2
  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    def f():
        # todo: check if it's actually a function or not before calling
        r = object.__getattribute__(self, name)()
        print 'hello world'
        return r
    return f
```

But I agree with the people who already left comments to your question: *is there an actual problem you're trying to solve here*?

Also, I think this hides the fact that there's something happening at the end of each method, and potentially obscures the code. Remember: explicit is better than implicit.

Of course you could put this into a class decorator:

```
def SaysHelloAfterEveryMethod(klass):
  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    def f():
      # todo: check if it's actually a function or not
      r = object.__getattribute__(self, name)()
      print 'hello world'
      return r
    return f
  klass.__getattribute__ = __getattribute__
  return klass

@SaysHelloAfterEveryMethod
class Example(object):
  def method1(self):
    print 1
  def method2(self):
    print 2
```

Comment: Or even better - make it a wrapper class!

Comment: @IdanArye Or use a decorator

Comment: Class decorators, how awesome is that? I will investigate that topic deeper. If there are other alternatives I'd also be interested. Like maybe there is a way to explicitly add the statement every time and error or warn in case it is not applied. That might also be a valid solution.

Comment: @erikb85 And if someone forgets to apply the class decorator? :P

Comment: @JonClements Then write a third class, which inherits the decorator and delegates it's constructor's argument to `Example`'s constructor. If you always use that third class, nobody will need to remember to apply the decorator.

Comment: What if I want to make a (private) helper function that I just want to use within other “public” methods? That would trigger that after-method action multiple times.

Comment: @poke Then you would probably add a simple `if` statement, checking if the name of the function starts with an underscore, or something trivial like that :-)